# How to sort a query in Elasticsearch based on another field?

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, lucene, full-text-search, elasticsearch-query

In Elasticsearch, I'm storing data as below:

```
{
  "name" : "John Doe",
  "country" : "India"
},
{
  "name" : "John Doe",
  "country" : "USA"
}
```

If user enter "John" than I'm searching by name field by querying as:

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 10,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "query_string": {
                        "query": "name:(John*)"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

And getting result something like from above query:

```
{
  "name" : "John Doe",
  "country" : "India"
},
{
  "name" : "John William",
  "country" : "USA"
},
{
  "name" : "John Smith",
  "country" : "Canada"
},
{
  "name" : "John Lobo",
  "country" : "India"
}
```

I'm getting all result with name John but I want John from country: India at top, after that Canada and than all other countries. That means I have to give more weightage to data with country=India, than country=Canada respectively.

Data with country=India and Canada should have more score in search results.

I found something **boost by value** feature in elasticsearch but not able to make query as required. Only one field value I can specify here.

```
{
    "query": {
        "boosting": {
            "positive": {
                "term": {
                    "country.keyword": "India"
                }
            },
            "negative": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
            "negative_boost": 0.5
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have written an answer for you, but since I'm not well-versed in Elasticsearch, there could be mistakes in my answer. Let me know whether it's useful.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/sort-search-results.html

you can apply script based sorting, the example given is

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": { "user": "kimchy" }
  },
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "type": "number",
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": "doc['field_name'].value * params.factor",
        "params": {
          "factor": 1.1
        }
      },
      "order": "asc"
    }
  }
}
```

As a result, you could pass the script you prefer, logically it could be an ascending sort on values of the like of

- India -> `AAAAA`
- Canada -> `AAAAB`
- otherwise you use the country name